# Is it possible to avoid copying arguments to a lambda function?

Tags: c++, function, lambda, c++14

I'd like to manage file descriptors using a Handle, and I want to use lambda expressions to process them. I'd like to use RAII to manage the underlying file descriptors. One option is to handle invalid values for descriptors (e.g. -1). However, I'd prefer for a handle to always be valid.

I've found that I can't seem to avoid invoking the copy constructor at least once. Here is a working example:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <functional>
#include <system_error>
#include <iostream>

class Handle
{
public:
    Handle(int descriptor) : _descriptor(descriptor) {}
    ~Handle()
    {
        std::cerr << "close(" << _descriptor << ")" << std::endl;
        ::close(_descriptor);
    }

    Handle(const Handle & other) : _descriptor(::dup(other._descriptor))
    {
        std::cerr << "dup(" << other._descriptor << ") = " << _descriptor << std::endl;
        if (_descriptor == -1) throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), "dup");
    }

    int descriptor() const { return _descriptor; }

private:
    int _descriptor;
};

Handle open_path(const char * path)
{
    return ::open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY);
}

void invoke(std::function<void()> & function)
{
    function();
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // Using auto f = here avoids the copy, but that's not helpful when you need a function to pass to another function.
    std::function<void()> function = [handle = open_path("/dev/random")]{
        std::cerr << "Opened path with descriptor: " << handle.descriptor() << std::endl;
    };

    invoke(function);
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
dup(3) = 4
close(3)
Opened path with descriptor: 4
close(4)
```

I know that the handle is being copied because it's being allocated by value within the `std::function`, but I was under the impression `std::function` could be heap allocated in some cases, which would perhaps avoid the copy (I guess this is not happening though).

There are a number of options, e.g. heap allocation, orusing a sentinel value (e.g. -1) which is checked. However, I'd like to have an invariant that a handle is always valid. It's sort of a matter of style and invariants.

Is there any way to construct the handle within the stack frame of the `std::function` to avoid copying, or do I need to take a different approach?

Perhaps as an additional point: to what extent can we rely on `std::function` to avoid copying it's arguments when it's created?

Comment: Why're you trying so ahrd to avoid the copy? Why not implement an efficient move con?

Comment: I'm going to be frank, I don't completely understand how the move constructor works, so if this is the solution, then it's something I'll spend more time trying to get my head around. Thanks.

Comment: Move constructors are perfect for these kind of situations (file descriptors etc), you basically just "steal" the descriptor from the old object without closing or reopening,

Comment: In this example, you could do `[&handle = open_path("/dev/random")]`.  But that becomes a problem if the `std::function` might have a lifetime longer than the block containing the lambda.

Comment: @RickAstley I think if you implement a move constructor you will still have the same issue of what state do you leave the moved-from handle in?

Comment: @chrisDrew Valid point, perhaps just signal that this handle is obsolete now.

Comment: @RickAstley Indeed, which is exactly what OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I must've missed the sentinel part, you're right. I don't think it's feasible having this approach however but I'm not OP.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to avoid the use of a sentinel as it makes the invariants of the class more complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's get this out of the way: `std::function` is completely orthogonal to lambdas. I wrote an article, [**"passing functions to functions"**](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html) that should clarify their relationship and illustrate various techniques that can be used to implement higher-order functions in modern C++.

> Using `auto f =` here avoids the copy, but that's not helpful when you need a function to pass to another function.

I disagree. You can use a template in `invoke` or something like `function_view` *(see LLVM's `FunctionRef` for a production-ready implementation, or my article for another simple implementation)*:

```
template <typename F>
void invoke(F&& function)
{
    std::forward<F>(function)();
}
```

```
void invoke(function_view<void()> function)
{
    function();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your article is very interesting and I do understand some of the points you made. In the past, I found significant performance overhead using std::function in inner loop, compared to using template. I'll digest what you've said and see if it works.

Comment: @ioquatix It's because the template approach takes the simple old fpointer approach. `std::function` has it's uses but for these cases the old approach is almost always better.

Comment: @RickAstley: unless I misunderstood what you're saying, not really. The `F` in the template is deduced to the anonymous type of the lambda - it does support stateful lambdas and it's conceptually easier to inline than a function pointer for the compiler, as there is no "runtime indirection".

Comment: @VittorioRomeo In this case definitely, you're correct. I meant the general case of passing a function to such a function expecting a callable.

Comment: So, I guess my problem is a tiny bit more complex. I'm working on a `Fiber` implementation. It's here: https://github.com/kurocha/concurrent/blob/master/source/Concurrent/Fiber.hpp#L44 - the problem is, the fiber resumes from a stack using `coentry` which can only handle a `void*` argument at present. Generally, it's working fine, but I wonder if I can make it more efficient using template lambda.

Comment: @ioquatix: well, if you need ownership of a generic `Callable `object *(i.e. you want to copy/move an existing `Callable` into some storage)* then `std::function` is probably what you want. Another approach is templatizing the whole `Fiber` thing with `F` and storing an `F` inside it, but that would still require you to copy/move the `Callable`. `function_view` and similar are only applicable when you want a non-owning reference to a function.

Comment: @ioquatix: note that your real use case is very different from your question - I suggest creating a new question with a minimal example closely modeling what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, in the first instance, this was my problem, trying to understand why the copying was happening and if there was any way around it. But as you explained, it's actually a poor idea to use `std::function` and I agree. Additionally, the nice thing about fibers is that they are still essentially stack based so ownership is a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Relying on elision or moving with `std::function` is not enough. Since `std::function` is required to be copyable, there's always a chance you might copy your `Handle` by accident elsewhere.

What you need to do instead is to wrap your `Handle` in something that will not invoke the copy constructor on copy. An obvious choice is a pointer. And an obvious choice of pointer would be a manged one like `std::shared_ptr`.

I made a few changes to your `Handle` class for testing (print statements for dtor, ctor, copy ctor), so I'll show those first:

```
class Handle
{
public:
    Handle(int descriptor) : _descriptor(descriptor) {std::cerr<<"Default ctor, descriptor: " << _descriptor << std::endl;}
    ~Handle()
    {
        std::cerr << "Dtor. close(" << _descriptor << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    Handle(const Handle & other) : _descriptor(other._descriptor+1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Copy ctor. dup(" << other._descriptor << ") = " << _descriptor << std::endl;
    }

    int descriptor() const { return _descriptor; }

private:
    int _descriptor;
};
```

Next let's modify `open_path` to return a `shared_ptr`:

```
std::shared_ptr<Handle> open_path(const char * path)
{
    return std::make_shared<Handle>(0);
}
```

And then we'll make a slight modification to our lambda in `main`:

```
std::function<void()> function = [handle = open_path("/dev/random")]{
        std::cerr << "Opened path with descriptor: " << handle->descriptor() << std::endl;
};
```

Our output now becomes:

```
Default ctor, descriptor: 0
Opened path with descriptor: 0
Dtor. close(0)
```

#### [Live Demo](http://rextester.com/XYRA55498)

Comment: This is an interesting solution but it requires memory allocation. I agree, it's one of several possible options, and I appreciate the length you've gone to, to give a working answer. It's very useful - thanks.